# Absence of new Bundle ID in the iTunes Connect drop menu

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I am trying to register an `APNS` enabled app on the  iTunes Connect portal. 
The `bundle ID` that my team created for this app is not available on the `Bundle ID` drop down menu on the `"App Information"` form.

Every Bundle ID that I created as an individual is there but not the one created as a company. 
Could the transition from individual to company affect the presence of the new `Bundle ID` in the iTunes Connect drop menu? 
If not, can anyone suggest an alternative reason why the `Bundle ID` is not available (it's been over 36 hours since it was created).

Thanks!

Comment: Follow up: It turned out that this problem was with the iTunes Connect portal. I contacted Apple Developer Technical Support and it took about two months, but they fixed the problem.